# Avoid Java compiler optimization of a loop and an if statement

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread and its main purpose is to process a list if there are items in it. This is done inside a loop:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    if (!jobs.isEmpty()) {
        final Job current = jobs.remove(0);
        current.start();
    }
}
```

While the thread is not interrupted it shall be checked if there are jobs in the list and if so they shall be executed.

But this code is optimized by the compiler (or JIT?) and the body of the if statement is never reached - even if there are items later. If I add some method call before the if block it works. The loop is necessary because the thread is run in an `ExecutorService` and I want to be able to stop its execution. So how can I avoid this optimization?

**Update**

This is what I am basically doing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    private final Worker worker = new Test.Worker();
    private final ExecutorService producer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Test().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        producer.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int cnt = 0;

                worker.add("Message " + cnt);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        worker.start();
    }

    public class Worker {

        private final List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        private final ExecutorService consumer = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        public synchronized void add(final String msg) {
            messages.add(msg);
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
            consumer.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        System.out.print("");

                        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println(messages.remove(0));
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it is highly unlikely that the JIT compiler is optimizing away the `if` statement.  If it did, that would be a compiler bug.

A far more likely explanation is that the `if` body is not being executed because the condition is never `true`; i.e. `jobs` queue (or whatever) is always empty ... according to `isEmpty()`.

> "*If I add System.out.println("not interrupted"); right before the if everything works and the console always outputs "not interrupted"*"

That could be due to other things.  For instance, doing some I/O within the loop could mean that some other thread gets a chance to put something onto the queue.

> "*The loop is necessary because the thread is run in an ExecutorService and I want to be able to stop its execution.*"

Actually, that is not necessary.  There are much better ways to do this.  For example.

1. Change `jobs` or `messages` or whatever to be some class that implements [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).  (For example, `ArrayBlockingQueue` will give you a bounded queue, if that is what you need.
2. Get rid of the loop.
3. Get rid of the `isEmpty` test.
4. Replace the `remove(0)` with a call to `take()`.

The `take()` call will block until either it succeeds in removing somethinf from the queue ... or the current thread is interrupted.  In the latter case, `InterruptedException` will be thrown.

This is likely to be both more reliable and LOTS more efficient than polling the interrupted flag and the queue in a tight loop.

Comment: The consumer should run all the time the main program is running. How can I do that if not in a loop?

Comment: OK ... if you need to loop for that reason, put the loop back in.

Answer (score 3):

The question you didn't ask, "What is a reasonable way to do what I'm trying to do?", is to use a [blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or [some other concurrent collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) for your `jobs` collection. You're constantly using CPU time to poll your `jobs` collection and check the `interrupted` flag. The concurrent collection classes have methods to poll the collection without constantly using CPU, and they'll handle interruption properly.